# Convert date from UTC to EST (Javascript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using Vue to render some data, the problem is the date stored in the field created_at is in UTC (I need it to be in EST).

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="result in results">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p>createdAt:{{ result._source.created_at }}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>text:{{ result._source.text }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using this javascript variable to convert it but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
<script>
   var usaTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
   console.log('USA time: '+ (new Date(usaTime)).toISOString())
</script>
```

Do I need to pass the value of created_at into a javascript function that will convert the date? Or could I just subtract eight hours from the date and then return it?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `Date` object which is in UTC, you can use your code to display it in a locale and timezone much as you did in your code.

Live demo:

```js
var utcTime = new Date("2020-10-16T18:00:00Z");
console.log('UTC Time: ' + utcTime.toISOString());
var usaTime = utcTime.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
console.log('USA time: '+ usaTime)
```

So

> Do I need to pass the value of created_at into a javascript function that will convert the date?

Yes, assuming your `result._source.created_at` value is formatted as a UTC date, you would pass it in and call `toLocaleString` to display it appropriately.

Perhaps something like:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
      <p>createdAt:{{ new Date(result._source.created_at).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York") }}</p>
 </div>
```